# How do I create multiple files names from list.txt in bash also change the text of that newly created file?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to create multiple files at a time using names from a file list.txt, as well as the text in each files.
Suppose I have a `list.txt` containing some `id`. numbers, now I want to make separate files using that ids as the name (e.g. `EOG090W002U_M0.ctl`, `EOG090W00C1_M0.ctl`, `EOG090W00DC_M0.ct`l). Also, the contents of the files need to be changed accordingly.

Sample `list.txt:`

```
EOG090W002U 
EOG090W00C1 
EOG090W00DC 
EOG090W00DE 
EOG090W00E5
EOG090W00HR 
EOG090W00MH 
EOG090W00MS 
EOG090W00PB 
EOG090W00U4
EOG090W00UK 
EOG090W00WM 
EOG090W00WR
```

For example the desired content of `EOG090W002U_M0.ctl`, `EOG090W00C1_M0.ctl` file will be

```
seqfile = EOG090W002U_p.phy
treefile = Sametree.txt
outfile = EOG090W002U_M0_mlc

getSE = 0
RateAncestor = 1
Small_Diff = 5e-7
cleandata = 1
fix_blength = 2
method = 0
```

Or

```
seqfile = EOG090W00C1_p.phy
treefile = Sametree.txt
outfile = EOG090W00C1_M0_mlc

  getSE = 0
  RateAncestor = 1
  Small_Diff = 5e-7
  cleandata = 1
  fix_blength = 2
  method = 0
```

Here, `seqfile` and `outfile` is going to be changed according to the `list.txt` but other texts in the file will remain the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `while` loop around a here-document:

```
while IFS= read -r x; do
  cat << EOF > "${x}_M0.ctl"
  seqfile = ${x}_p.phy
  treefile = Sametree.txt
  outfile = ${x}_M0_mlc

    getSE = 0
    RateAncestor = 1
    Small_Diff = 5e-7
    cleandata = 1
    fix_blength = 2
    method = 0
EOF
done < list.txt
```

---

If lines in your `list.txt` have leading or trailing SPC or TAB characters that should **not** be interpreted as part of the file name (and you have not otherwise modified the `IFS` variable), then omit the `IFS=` assignment before the `read` command:

```
while read -r x; do
```

Or explicitly set it to SPC and TAB:

```
while IFS=$' \t' read -r x; do
```

(note that expanding it to other whitespace characters like `CR`, `FF`, `NBSP`... won't work as they don't receive the special IFS whitespace treatment, only SPC, TAB and NL do).

Comment: Thanks, but files are created empty.

Comment: files are empty because of the way cat is directing the output file. it should be cat << EOF >> "${x}_M0.ctl"

Comment: I'll edit the code above.

Comment: @BANJOSA why do you believe the redirection needs to be `>>` rather than `>`?

Comment: @steeldriver: you are right, it doesn't need it. In my previous testing I've made a typo that resulted in a bad execution. I've modified it as I proposed and worked. Now I've made a test again with your script and worked as expected, except the indentation of the first 3 lines that is now exactly as requested by the OP. Given that is a minor issue, I apologize for the proposed correction and will vote your response up.

Comment: Thnaks, but thing is that, it is creating space after the variable ${x} like the file name created EOG090W002U _M0.ctl. Same way the inside the file     
seqfile = EOG090W034W
_p.phy
  treefile = Sametree.txt
  outfile = EOG090W034W
_M0_mlc

So, there is a clear space between the variable and the extension. How can I get rid of this problem.

Thanks

Comment: That is happening because you have those spaces in the file name list. Remove the spaces after the name in the original list or use the solution below given by @vikram Tidake

Comment: The script given by @steeldriver giving best result till now though the space is the big issue..

Comment: @DebajyotiKabiraj I have suggested a workaround for the whitespace

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
tr -d '[:blank:]' < list.txt > outputFile.tmp

for i in $(cat outputFile.tmp)
do
  echo "seqfile = ${i}_p.phy" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
  echo "treefile = Sametree.txt" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
  echo "outfile = ${i}_M0_mlc" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
  echo "" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
  echo "getSE = 0" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
  echo "RateAncestor = 1" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
  echo "Small_Diff = 5e-7" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
  echo "cleandata = 1" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
  echo "fix_blength = 2" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
  echo "method = 0" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
done
exit 0
```